# C# WPF app won't compile when I try to use newly added app settings

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config

A WPF app I've written will no longer compile when I try to use a recently added app setting in my code behind. I can see the setting in the settings designer and in the app config, and will compile if I comment out a reference to the setting.

The new setting is intended to store a date that informs it when to show a balloon tip if minimized. It appears any newly added setting breaks the build, regardless of what type it is.

Is there a step to adding new settings I'm not aware of?

Here's what it looks like:

```
//designer, pretty much the same as all the other declarations:

[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public global::System.DateTime BaloonLastSeen {
   get {
      return ((global::System.DateTime)(this["BaloonLastSeen"]));
   }
   set {
       this["BaloonLastSeen"] = value;
   }
}

<!-- app.config: -->

<userSettings>
    <MyNS.MyApp>
        <setting name="WindowState" serializeAs="String">
            <value>-1</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="BaloonLastSeen" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
    </MyNS.MyApp>
</userSettings>

//and finally, my attempt to use it in code-behind:

System.DateTime baloon = Properties.Settings.Default.BaloonLastSeen;
```

Calls to other properties through `Properties.Settings.Default` work just fine, it's only recently added ones it seems to be tripping over. I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, and even restarting Visual Studio, but it doesn't seem to help.

One other piece of information is that an attempt to call this property breaks intellisense. After the failed attempt to build, VS will no longer detect types or member names as I'm typing until I restart.

Here's what the compiler says is wrong:

```
Error   31  'MyNS.MyApp.Properties.Settings' does not contain a definition for 'BaloonLastSeen' and no extension method 'BaloonLastSeen' accepting a first argument of type 'MyNS.MyApp.Properties.Settings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What have I wrought!?

Comment: What exactly is the compiler error message?

Comment: I added the specific compiler error.

Comment: Most odd. I guess you've checked the namespace is correct in the resources source file. Have you tried deleting /debug and /release folders and deleting the .suo file before rebuilding?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'm grasping at straws, the only aspect which looks slightly out-of-kilter to me are the MyNS.MyApp tags in the app.config which I believe should be MyNS.MyApp.Properties.Settings e.g.

```
<!-- app.config: -->

<userSettings>
    <MyNS.MyApp.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="WindowState" serializeAs="String">
            <value>-1</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="BaloonLastSeen" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
    </MyNS.MyApp.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```